# Как перебрать массив начиная с определённого ключа?

Tags: php, сессия, foreach

У меня есть цикл foreach, в котором $key работает как счетчик, потому что там 1,2,3...

Хочу сохранять состояние этого счетчика на момент завершения программы в $_SESSION['confinement'], чтобы когда программа будет запущена в следующий раз, массив перебирался с того места, на котором в прошлый раз цикл остановился.. Почему-то не срабатывает.. Никак не пойму, почему. Может, кто-то более опытный уделит время и подскажет? Был бы очень благодарен.. Извините за беспокойство..

```
<?php
$arr = [
    1 => ['Яблоко', 'Груша', 'Морковь'],
    2 => ['Арбуз', 'Свекла', 'Дыня'],
    3 => ['Калина', 'Земляника', 'Клубника'],
    4 => ['Алыча', 'Персик', 'Слива'],
    5 => ['Крыжовник', 'Рябина', 'Клубника'],
    6 => ['Земляника', 'Нектарин', 'Персик'],
    ];


// как из сессии положить данные в переменную php

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($value);
    echo '</pre>';
    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        $key + 1;
        $_SESSION['confinement'] = $key;
        break;
    }
    $_SESSION['confinement'] = $key;
}
```

Обновление информации 20.10.2020:

Попробовал вывести $key сессией.. скрипт висит, но ничего не выводит. Зато если "вардампить" просто $key вывод работает.

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
    /*var_dump(substr($value, 21));*/
    $cut = substr($value, 128);
   $output = 'https://yandex.ru/search/xml?user=englishforcingmailadress&key=03.381436252:c06fde163d8d5f31e630dd1e925ebc56&query=' . urlencode($cut) . '&lr==ru&sortby=&filter=none&maxpassages=5&groupby=ocs-in-group%3D3';

     $result = file_get_contents($output);
    /*  var_dump($result);*/
     $fp = fopen("xml.txt", "a+");
   fwrite($fp, $result);
   fclose($fp);
   sleep(0.10);

}
```

$_SESSION['lo'] = $key;
var_dump($_SESSION['lo']);

Comment: Главная беда, конечно, этого сайта - это формулировки вопросов.

Comment: хотел просто заострить.. т.к. интересно именно с помощью сессии такую проблему решить.. хотел по конкретнее выразиться..

Comment: Ну да, конечно. "У меня вот этот чел в магазине украл кошелек! Ну то есть кошелька у меня никогда и не было, я просто заострить хотел"

Comment: Ты мог бы поинтересоваться, а можно ли вообще сохранить состояние счетчика. Никто ведь не мешает тебе попробовать его "запомнить" без всяких сессий?

Comment: ну что? никто очевидное решение с continue по условию не напишет?

Comment: @Ипатьев я что-туплю уже что ли, но тоже не пойму, как можно состояние счетчика *"запомнить" без всяких сессий*? Подскажите плз что имеется в виду)

Comment: @Ипатьев Почитал про continue (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php). Но сам по себе он, наверное не решит проблемы. Поправьте, если не прав. Мне нужно будет по расписанию из крона запускать несколько раз скрипт.. при этом цикл должен возобновлять работу с того, на чем остановился.. Без сессии, но с continue он с новым запуском просто начнет работать сначала, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: для начала я не понял, какое отношение сессии имеют к крону.

Comment: но в целом логика верна: если не запомнить позицию, то цикл будет работать сначала. тут тебя можно только поздравить с такой гениальной догадкой.

Comment: Крон упомянул, чтобы лучше проинформировать о проблеме.. Цикл не просто должен прерываться, а возобновлять с того, чем кончил каждый раз, как программа будет заново запускается.. Только continue с этим не поможет, правильно? А как в таком случае?

Comment: Если у Вас с этим все работает только один пользователь - записывайте на каждой итерации цикла значение нужно переменной во временный файл. При старте скрипта проверяйте на его наличие считывайте состояние переменной из него. При нормальном окончании работы скрипта - удаляйте этот файл.

Comment: А как это сделать? Никогда не сталкивался...